# View does not return to center after animation

Tags: android, animation, kotlin, position, android-animation

So I have an animated view that I want to return to the center of the screen once the animation is done. I use this code to get the center of the view to the center of the screen:

```
    val screencenterX = (FullscreenActivity.metrics.widthPixels - mContentView.width) / 2
    val screencenterY = (FullscreenActivity.metrics.heightPixels - mContentView.height) / 2

    val soultostartx = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mContentView, "x", screencenterX.toFloat()).apply {
        duration = 1
    }
    val soultostarty = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mContentView, "y", screencenterY.toFloat()).apply {
        duration = 1
    }

    fun toStart() = AnimatorSet().apply {
        play(soultostartx).with(soultostarty)
        start()
    }

toStart()
```

This works fine in portrait mode, but as soon as the phone is rotated to landscape, the view in question moves somewhere in the lower left quarter of the screen instead. Any idea why that might be? The maths for getting the center of the screen should be the same, or not?

----------------------------------Edit-----------------------------------

Following the answer by ismail alaoui, I added the following code in my Activity:

```
override fun onConfigurationChanged(myConfig: Configuration) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(myConfig)
    val orient = resources.configuration.orientation
    when (orient) {
        Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE -> {
            (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
            println("landscape orient")
        }
        Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT -> {
            (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
            println("portrait orient")
        }
        else -> {
            (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED)
            println("else orient")
        }
    }
}
```

I have added the calls to println() to see if the onConfigurationChanged() is really called, and it is. But it seems to have no effect at all. Is there something I need to add to the when-cases?

Answer (score 1):

It happened because when you turn your phone your view is recreated , you should override this method in your activity:

```
@Override 
public void  onConfigurationChanged(Configuration myConfig) 

 { 
  super.onConfigurationChanged(myConfig); 
  int orient = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

  switch(orient) 
  {
   case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE: setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
     break; 
    case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:        

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); 
   break; 
   default:
     setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED); 
       }
  }
```

Do not forget to add `android:configChange:"orientation|screenSize"` 
To your activity tag in manifest

**edit**

kotlin : [check this tuto](https://tutorial.eyehunts.com/android/set-entire-android-application-portrait-mode-portrait-orientation-kotlin/)

Comment: `setRequestedOrientation` gets an unresolved reference error when translated to kotlin. Any idea how to deal with that?

Comment: Thanks for the link!